# Generate policy and signature values to store data directly from HTML post request to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
import base64
import hmac, hashlib
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AKIAIHHMU7Y4L2INOFRQ'

policy_document = {
    "expiration": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "conditions": [ {"bucket": "report-generation1"},
                    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
                    {"acl": "private"},
                    {"success_action_redirect": "localhost/";},
                    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
                    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
                   ]
                  }

policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())
```

I need to generate policy and signature values to store data directly from HTML post request to Amazon S3 bucket.

The above program gives error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'..

Comment: policy_document = {"expiration": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "conditions": [ 
    {"bucket": "report-generation1"}, 
    ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
    {"acl": "private"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
  ]
}

Comment: Which line is generating the error? Also, your Secret Access Key is a long line of random characters, not the one you have shown. (You have shown the Access Key, not the Secret Access Key.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Got it working.

You had a stray semi-colon. Also, `b64encode` requires a string rather than a dictionary, so just put the object inside quotes.

```
import base64
import hmac, hashlib
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<your-secret-access-key>'

policy_document = '{"expiration": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z", "conditions": [ {"bucket": "report-generation1"}, ["starts-with", "$key", ""], {"acl": "private"}, {"success_action_redirect": "localhost/"}, ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""], ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]]}'

policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())
```

Also, please note that you supplied your `Access Key` instead of the `Secret Access Key`.